# USB flash drive not showing up

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, usb, gparted

On my dual-boot system, I cannot see my USB flash drive on the Windows or Ubuntu desktop or in gparted (after clicking on the upper-right spinbox to make sure I am not looking at /sda). I looked at the forums but could not find the solution for my specific problem.

Screenshots of possible value intel [fdisck & lsusb](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DgCnB.png) [dmesg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Y3uD.png) [lsblk](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E2RTn.png)

Comment: try running "dmesg -w" in a terminal and see if anything happens when you plug/unplug your device

Comment: Joshua B, it appeared on desktop! amazing, thank you. But i did unplug/replug a 2nd time to screenshot you the "what to do with flash window" without ejecting it... so sorry about that, that was excitment, and it doesnt show up anymore... any quick tip ?

Comment: maybe the contacts on the drive were dirty and the multiple plug/unplug cycles cleaned it? not sure what fixed it but good to hear it's working for you!

Comment: redid all dmesg -w manip a few times and it finally worked again. thank you so much, problem solved!!! will eject next times ;)

Comment: dmesg -w just shows your system messages as they are happening and won't actually fix anything.... it's more for debugging to see if your system actually sees the drive when it's plugged in... must've been dirty contacts

Comment: would you suggest something like formating, clean it and create new partition, even table ?

Comment: Posted all in an answer for you.

Comment: BTW, in the future, it is best to copy and paste output from commands and format it with the "code" formatting instead of posting screenshots.

Comment: as you can guess, i am not a genius with that matter, what "format it with the "code" formatting" mean ? also i think i voted already, not even sure, but how to mark as answered or solved ?

Comment: to the left of the answer there are arrows up and down with a number in the middle, those are for voting. under that there should be a checkmark button to "accept answer".... to format text as code, select the text to be formatted and and click the {} button at the top of the text entry window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Likely a Hardware Problem**

If the drive is not showing up at all on any system, likely something is wrong with the drive itself. It could have dirty contacts, been damaged or has reached the end of its life.

First thing to do is clean the contacts on the drive. Perhaps just a few plugs/unplugs will fix it.

Next, you can run a command to see if your computer even sees the drive when it's plugged in. In a terminal run:

```
dmesg -w
```

And watch for output as you plug/unplug the drive. Does the system see it? Does it output any errors?

If at this point your computer is completely non reactive to the plugging in of the drive, it's time to get a new drive.

If the drive is working intermittently, when it does actually mount, backup all of your data from the drive and COMPLETELY reformat it (new partition table and partition), and replace the data. If the reformatting doesn't make the drive reliable, it's time to replace it.